# How does the size of datasets influence the accuracy of ARIMA-forecasting?

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arima

I got a dataset with around 15000 entries. It casts the free Memory of an server every 10 minutes and has every night more space and once in a month very little.
If i split this data in ~75% traindata and want to forecast the other 25%, the forecast gets a straight line/ is the same for every forecasting step (at round about the mid of the train data) even though the train data has a very specific pattern. So the forecasting does not even closly alternate.

Do you know why this could happen? I tried a lot of different models iincluding SARIMA models and all this does not help. Could it be that 15000 datapoints is too large for arima, so that it can not handle it? 
In this picture you can see the forecast vs. the actual data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0v6wdtselrspqd8/Capture.PNG?dl=0

I would be so happy if someone could tell me whats wrong! :)

Comment: Please post some data and the code otherwise the "Cross Validated" site (https://stats.stackexchange.com/) would be the best place to ask such a question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your data does not contain any strong seasonality and trend and the arima() is not able to find forecast accurate because of that.

Therefore it is simply taking average of your historical data and returning as forecast. therefore the values are same (you will get straight line when you plot it.)